# Structure of finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[[S,T]]$-modules

Tags: nt.number-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, iwasawa-theory

Let $\Omega=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[[S,T]]$. $\Omega$ is a commutative, Noetherian and integrally closed domain of Krull dimension 2. According to Bourbaki's commutative algebra VII $\S 4$, if $M$ is a finitely generated $\Omega$-module, then there are $r,s \in \mathbb{Z}$, prime ideals $\mathfrak{p}_i$ of height 1 and an exact sequence

$$0 \to A \to M \to \Omega^r\oplus\bigoplus_{i=1}^s\Omega/\mathfrak{p}_i^{n_i} \to B \to 0$$
where $A$ and $B$ are finite.

Now let $n >1$ and consider the $\Omega'=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}[[S,T]]$. Of course $\Omega'$ is not an integral domain. Is there any structure theorem for finitely generated $\Omega'$-modules?